# Adobe Live Search Installation/Config problems

Tags: magento2, extensions, search, elasticsearch, saas

I know this question is super generic, but is anyone else having just a helluva time getting Adobe Live Search installed, configured and enabled?!?  I've been trying (apparently unsuccessfully) running through their documentation the last few days, and am getting nowhere.

I've got all my Prod/Sandbox API keys in, the module installed and just am getting nothing back.

On top of that, it appears that `bin/magento module:disable Magento_Elasticsearch Magento_Elasticsearch6 Magento_Elasticsearch7 Magento_ElasticsearchCatalogPermissions Magento_AdvancedSearch Magento_InventoryElasticsearch`

...throws errors saying that there are several modules that depend on it.  Mmmk... so then Adobe, why are you telling me to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

***You must follow these steps:***

The following describes how to proceed to install Live Search.

a) Move to the base path of the magento project, Open the command console.

b) Install LiveSearch

```
composer require magento/live-search:^2.0
```

c) Disable modules related to Elasticsearch

bin/magento module:disable Magento_Elasticsearch Magento_Elasticsearch7 Magento_Elasticsearch6 Magento_ElasticsearchCatalogPermissions Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_ElasticsearchCatalogPermissionsGraphQl

d) Run the command:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Install Connector:

```
composer require magento/experience-platform-connector:^1.0
```

2. Run the command:

   bin/magento setup:upgrade
3. Clear cache

   bin/magento c:c
4. Update live search by running the command:

   composer update magento/live-search --with-dependencies
5. Run the command to view the installed live search data:

   composer show magento/live-search
6. run: `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
7. The following modules should be activated if they were not already activated:

   bin/magento module:enable Magento_LiveSearchAdapter Magento_LiveSearchStorefrontPopover Magento_LiveSearch Magento_LiveSearchMetrics Magento_LiveSearchTerms

   bin/magento module:enable Magento_SaaSCommon Magento_SaaSCatalog Magento_SaaSProductOverride Magento_ExperienceConnectorAdmin Magento_ExperienceConnector Magento_ServicesIdGraphQlServer Magento_ServicesId Magento_DataServices Magento_ServicesConnector

   bin/magento module:enable Magento_BundleProductDataExporter Magento_CatalogDataExporter Magento_CatalogInventoryDataExporter Magento_CatalogUrlRewriteDataExporter Magento_ConfigurableProductDataExporter Magento_DataExporter Magento_ParentProductDataExporter Magento_ProductOverrideDataExporter

   bin/magento module:enable Magento_GraphQl Magento_AdminGraphQlServer Magento_DataServicesMultishipping Magento_QueryXml Magento_ServicesIdLayout Magento_GraphQlServer
8. `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
9. `Clear cache: bin/magento c:c`
10. If necessary, run the following command: rm -rf pub/static/*/* && rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* && bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && bin/magento cache:flush

In the graphical interface Admin: System -> Commerce Services Connector

12. Click on Start setup to configure the credentials, select the project and the Space assigned by Adobe
13. Click on next, the public and private keys will be requested both to enter said credentials in the spaces assigned for it.
14. To enter the Live Search panel, Marketing -> SEO & Search -> Live Search

If the credentials were entered correctly, the respective panel will be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, and on top of that, the products disappear from the frontend. I tried to do a reindex, but it is not working.